# Permutations disjoint cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Write the following permutation into a product of disjoint cycles?

(145)(256)(35)

I'm unsure as to how do this?

Comment: Trace where the elements go and you will get $(146235)$. For example, first cycle moves 1 to 4, second moves 4 to 4 and third moves 4 to 4. Thus 1 moves to 4. Now, first moves 4 to 5, second moves 5 to 6 and third moves 6 to 6. Thus 4 moves to 6 etc

Comment: Do you first understand how to write the product of cycles as a single permutation in two-row form?  What does your permutation do to the number $1$?  what does it do to $2$?  to $3$?  Now, from that way of reading it, letting our permutation be called $\pi$, what is $1$?  what is $\pi(1)$?  what is $\pi(\pi(1))$?  $\pi(\pi(\pi(1)))$? etc... if all numbers didn't appear, then pick the next number that you haven't seen yet and ask the same series of questions for it.

Answer (score 1):

From right to left follow the "cycle" of each element, and when it gets closed take the next unused number:

$$1\to4\;,\;\;4\to 5\;,\;\;5\to3\;,\;\;3\to 5\to 6\;,\;\;6\to2\;,\;\;2\to5\to1...\text{closed}$$

and we already have the cycle $\;(1\;4\;5\;3\;6\;2)\;$...and since no digit between $\;1\;$ to $\;6\;$ is unused we're done.

If we had for example $\;(1347)(2537) = (1\;3)(2\;5\;4\;7)\;$ . Why? Because

$$1\to3\;,\;\;3\to7\to1...\text{closed, so we take}\;\;2\to5\;,\;\;5\to3\to 4\;,\;\;4\to 7\;,\;\;7\to2...\text{closed}$$

and we get both cycles above.

Answer (score 0):

Just see where each element goes. Follow the cycles from right to left (I hope that this is the convention of your textbook), and inside a  cycle follow the elements from left to right.

$1\mapsto 4$

$2\mapsto5\mapsto 1$

$3\mapsto 5\mapsto 6$

$4\mapsto5$

$5\mapsto3 $

$6\mapsto2$

Hence in two-row notation we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
4&1&6&5&3&2
\end{pmatrix}$$
As a product of disjoint cycles we have
$$(145362)$$
so just one cycle!